# Rails 3 update View with JS after new record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am fetching tweets using the `tweetstream gem` and I create a record for every single tweet. `index.html.erb` lists all the saved tweets. But I have to reload manually to see the new ones.

How do I get startet with a JS/jQuery code that should watch the records in my database and update the view/append the new tweet everytime a new record is saved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could use a javascript time out function to loop on a loaded page checking for updates, see above link for the examples.

Comment: I am looking for something like Twitter uses on their page. In the case of a new post, a button which says "new tweets, klick to update page" pops up and the user can klick to show the new tweets.